# CanvasJS with Angular 11: You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders

Tags: angular, angular11, canvasjs

I try to use CanvasJS into an Angular 11 project, but I have an error with the import:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/canvasjs/src/charts/index.js 1:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:7)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/babel/webpack-loader.js
 * ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> export SplineChart from '../charts/spline';
| export ColumnChart from '../charts/column';
| export StackedColumnChart from '../charts/stacked_column';
```

package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
  ...
  "canvasjs": "^1.8.3",
  ...
},
"devDependencies": {
  ...
  "@types/canvasjs": "^1.9.7",
```

My import in my component looks like this (no error):

```
import * as CanvasJS from 'canvasjs';
```

I initialize the chart (code from sample) on ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  let chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
    animationEnabled: true,
    exportEnabled: true,
    title: {
      text: "Basic Column Chart in Angular"
    },
    data: [{
      type: "column",
        dataPoints: [
          { y: 71, label: "Apple" },
          { y: 55, label: "Mango" },
          { y: 50, label: "Orange" },
          { y: 65, label: "Banana" },
          { y: 95, label: "Pineapple" },
          { y: 68, label: "Pears" },
          { y: 28, label: "Grapes" },
          { y: 34, label: "Lychee" },
          { y: 14, label: "Jackfruit" }
        ]
    }]
  });
  
  chart.render();
}
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using outdated / unofficial version of CanvasJS. Follow the below steps to add CanvasJS charts in your Angular application.

1. Download the official version from [CanvasJS Download Page](https://canvasjs.com/download-html5-charting-graphing-library/) / commercial version from [My Account Page](https://canvasjs.com/my-account/).
2. Save canvasjs.min.js in app folder
3. Import the library

   ```
   import * as CanvasJS from './canvasjs.min';
   ```
4. Create & render chart

   ```
   var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart({
     //Chart Options Goes Here
   });
   chart.render();
   ```

Check out [CanvasJS Angular Gallery](https://canvasjs.com/angular-charts/) for more examples with code / samples that you can download & run locally. [Here is a live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/canvasjs-column-chart-angular-12).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't put teh solution but it's exactly what I have found. At first, I use the minified js from node_modules.